# Class not found, unmarshalling error when trying to make a multiplayer game with play store

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, unmarshalling

So I'm trying to make a multiplayer game with friends. For the multiplayer part, I connected the project to the developer console and copied some sample code provided by Google, the classic button clicker, to see how the coding works. The problem is, when I run it and send an invite to someone, it doesn't work. The invite shows up on the other device but when it accepts it, the project only works on one phone and stops working on the other. I am using actual devices, not emulators. This is the log cat.

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=10002, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {ml.digits/ml.digits.MultiPlayerSignIn}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room ID must not be null or empty
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4058)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4101)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1497)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room ID must not be null or empty
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1548)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService$Stub$Proxy.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.RealTimeMultiplayerImpl.sendUnreliableMessage(Unknown Source)
        at ml.digits.MultiPlayerSignIn.broadcastScore(MultiPlayerSignIn.java:760)
        at ml.digits.MultiPlayerSignIn.startGame(MultiPlayerSignIn.java:638)
        at ml.digits.MultiPlayerSignIn.onActivityResult(MultiPlayerSignIn.java:229)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6549)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4054)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4101)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1497)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Oddly enough, when I try to send the invite from the other device, it connects the two devices and the game starts. In the game, you should be able to see your score and the other players score, However, you can only see both scores on one device and in the other, you can only see your own score. Here's the logcat for that.

```
    E/Parcel﹕ Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomEntity
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomEntity
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:272)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2275)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2146)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5386)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1811)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1364)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4727)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4572)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:140)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3093)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomEntity" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:272)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2275)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2146)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5386)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1811)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1364)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4727)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4572)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:140)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3093)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomEntity
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 18 more
```

Last but not least, here's the code for the method in the MultiPlayerSignIn.class that throws the error.

```
 if (finalScore) {
            Log.d(TAG, "This is the room"+mRoomId);
            // final score notification must be sent via reliable message
                Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage(mGoogleApiClient, null, mMsgBuf,
                        mRoomId, p.getParticipantId());

        } else {
            // it's an interim score notification, so we can use unreliable
             Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendUnreliableMessage(mGoogleApiClient, mMsgBuf, mRoomId,
                        p.getParticipantId());
        }
```

Here's where the room is being created. It's null when it shouldnt be

```
     // Accept the given invitation.
void acceptInviteToRoom(String invId) {
    // accept the invitation
    Log.d(TAG, "Accepting invitation: " + invId);
    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    roomConfigBuilder.setInvitationIdToAccept(invId)
            .setMessageReceivedListener(this)
            .setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
    keepScreenOn();
    resetGameVars();
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.join(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfigBuilder.build());
}
```

Thanks for any help (: [Here's](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/ButtonClicker/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/bc/MainActivity.java) where I got the code from.

Comment: You've included, way too much code, perhaps shrink it to only what we need to see, which in this case is how you are communicating with the google library. Also for the ClassNotFoundException, did you check to make sure those stub classes are being included in your application and that they are being resolved? That is super important. Read the documentation about the library on how to include it into your project.

Comment: Are you using emulators or real devices? If you're using emulators, make sure they're using "Google API's" system images.

Comment: So I tried cutting down the code, but as you can see, its still long because I'm not sure what to cut since I don't know what is causing the exception. The stub class should be in the application and it is in the manifest file. I'm also using devices, not emulators.

Comment: @JoxTraex After doing some debugging with the logcat I realized that the error gets thrown with this method                Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage

Comment: With the new information, you should update your post and reflect that new information. Also as @Barend said, you need ot tell us if you are using an emulator or actual device, this is actually useful information sometimes.

Comment: @JoxTraex, In my first comment, I mentioned that I was using actual devices, I edited the post to reflect that as well and added the specific code throwing the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to insert `mRoomId = room.getRoomId()` in the `onJoinedRoom`-Method:

```
public void onJoinedRoom(int statusCode, Room room) {

    ...

    mRoomId = room.getRoomId();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens with Google's example code as well.
I see it on my Samsung device.
Are you on Samsung Note as well?

A Google engineer claims it has no impact on functionality:

https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples/issues/17